# how to use while loop in mysql array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called vw_results which holds the result profile for a particular student:

```
idNum |courseUnit | marks | Gpp | grade| id | semseterID | sessionName

06/021|   2       | 47    | 8   |  B+  | 1  |   1        |  2010/11
06/021|   3       | 56    | 7   |  C   | 1  |   1        |  2010/11
.     |   4       | 34    | 5   |  C   | 1  |   1        |  2010/11
.     |   5       | 34    | 0   |  F   | 1  |   1        |  2010/11
.     |   2       | 89    | 10  |  A   | 1  |   2        |  2010/11
.     |   3       | 45    | 4   |  D   | 1  |   2        |  2010/11
.     |   4       | 56    | 10  |  C   | 1  |   2        |  2010/11
.     |   2       | 67    | 12  |  B+  | 2  |   1        |  2011/12
.     |   1       | 70    | 15  |  A   | 2  |   1        |  2011/12
.     |   2       | 80    | 10  |  A   | 2  |   2        |  2011/12
.     |   3       | 90    | 5   |  A   | 2  |   2        |  2011/12
```

To calculate the GPA

```
"SELECT SUM( vwr.courseUnit ) cummUnit, SUM( vwr.GPP ) cummGPP, (
SUM( vwr.GPP ) / SUM( vwr.courseUnit ))cummGPA
FROM vw_result vwr
WHERE vwr.Grade NOT IN ('F') AND vwr.sessionID=".$_GET['sessionID']." AND vwr.semesterID=".$_GET['semesterID'].";"
```

if $_GET['sessionID']=1 and $_GET['semesterID']=2
then

```
|cummGPA|
|1.913  |
```

if $_GET['sessionID']=2 and $_GET['semesterID']=1
then

```
|cummGPA|
|2.730  |
```

if $_GET['sessionID']=2 and $_GET['semesterID']=2
then

```
|cummGPA|
|2.774  |
```

any suggestions on how to go about this?!
THANKS!

Comment: One advice. Reduce your question to a simple example and use much less code.

Comment: I can't understood what you want!!!

Comment: @Steve : I have removed the redundant code..

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I want to calculate the GPA in a cummulative manner i.e when the form variables (sessionID=2 and semesterID=2) it should include in the final calculation results of the GPA calulation when the form variables are 1-1;1-2;2-1

Answer (score 0):

Uff, you should ask more clearly, no one will take time to understand you question. Its just that I have nothing to do..

If i understand what you want correctly then it will be:

```
select count(id) from vw_results group by (id, semseterID) having (id=1 and semseterID=1)  or (id=1 and semseterID=2) or (id=2 and semseterID=1) or (id=2 and semseterID=2)
```

Hope it will work, never tried it.